# I'm having trouble locating a linkText with <em> tag in selenium with java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

the HTML looks like

```
<span class="linktext"><em>M</em>asters</span>

xpath - //*[@id="mastersNavButton"]/span
```

I tried with below codes but didn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="mastersNavButton"]/span"));

driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("asters")).click();
```

Comment: Hi, does the HTML code you posted correct?

Comment: Yes it is. Another example is : <span class="linktext"><em>L</em>ogout</span>.

Answer (score 0):

First check this:

```
List<WebElement> emElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("em"));
System.out.println(emElements.size());
```

If you get 0, you'll need to wait until the page is loaded and elements reachable by selenium and/or switch to frame.
See this https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html
and this https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'linktext')]//em[contains(text(),'M')]").click()
```